# Unable to get vCalendar (vcs) to be time adjusted when opened in different time zone

Tags: php, vcalendar

I am creating a .vcs file using the iCalcreator (v2.6) PHP library. When the event is opened in Outlook (newest version, I don't know about other versions), the meeting date/time is not adjusted to the local time. I thought it might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150595/outlook-not-importing-vcs-with-timezones-correctly), but setting the X-MICROSOFT-CDO-TZID value did not seem to help. I'm hoping someone knows something about vcs file creation who can point me in the right direction. Here is the vcs file that I am creating:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:-//127.0.53.53//NONSGML iCalcreator 2.6//
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:US/Pacific
LAST-MODIFIED:20040110T032845Z
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-TZID:13
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:19900404T010000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0800
TZOFFSETTO:-0700
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=4;BYDAY=1SU
TZNAME:PDT
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:19901026T060000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0700
TZOFFSETTO:-0800
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
TZNAME:PST
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:20170413T205736CEST-5403Nbu2Iu@127.0.53.53
DTSTAMP:20170413T185736Z
DESCRIPTION:sdfg\n\nSome awesome description
DTSTART:20170419T180000
DURATION:PT3H0M0S
LOCATION:The best place in the world
SUMMARY:One fine summary
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

Years late, but here's how it works for me, and maybe this will help anyone else who happens upon this question.

I've never tried TZOFFSETFROM...so not sure what that's about or even if it should work.  However, if you put the Timezone in the DTSTART and DTEND, it will automatically adjust.  You just need the date to be in UTC like your LAST-MODIFIED date.  I do it like this (`$start` and `$end` are PHP DateTime objects):

```
"DTSTART:".$start->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'))->format('Ymd\THis\Z').$eol.
"DTEND:".$end->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'))->format('Ymd\THis\Z')
```

So, basically, all that does is put the date into the UTC timezone and then format the date/time with a Z at the end to communicate this to the client.

A full working example (in the event it's helpful to anyone) is:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    //CONFIGURE HERE
    $fromName           = "John Doe";
    $fromEmail          = "john.doe@example.com";
    $toName             = "Your Name";
    $toEmail            = 'yourname@example.com';
    $start              = new DateTime('2017-08-15 15:00');
    $end                = new DateTime('2017-08-15 16:00');
    $summary            = "Hello World Event";
    //END CONFIGURATION

    $uid                = "0123456789";
    $headers            = array();
    $boundary           = "_CAL_" . uniqid("B",true) . "_B_";
    $headers[]          = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers[]          = "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"".$boundary."\"";
    $headers[]          = "To: \"{$toName}\" <{$toEmail}>";
    $headers[]          = "From: \"{$fromName}\" <{$fromEmail}>";

    $calendarLines      = array(
        "BEGIN:VCALENDAR",
        "METHOD:REQUEST",
        "PRODID:-//PHP//MeetingRequest//EN",
        "VERSION:2.0",
        "BEGIN:VEVENT",
        "ORGANIZER;CN={$fromName}:MAILTO:{$fromEmail}",
        "ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN={$toName}:MAILTO:{$toEmail}",
        "DESCRIPTION:{$summary}",
        "SUMMARY:{$summary}",
        "DTSTART:".$start->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'))->format('Ymd\THis\Z'),
        "DTEND:".$end->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'))->format('Ymd\THis\Z'),
        "UID:{$uid}",
        "CLASS:PUBLIC",
        "PRIORITY:5",
        "DTSTAMP:".gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z'),
        "TRANSP:OPAQUE",
        "STATUS:CONFIRMED",
        "SEQUENCE:0",
        "LOCATION:123 Any Street",
        "BEGIN:VALARM",
        "ACTION:DISPLAY",
        "DESCRIPTION:REMINDER",
        "TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M",
        "END:VALARM",
        "END:VEVENT",
        "END:VCALENDAR"
    );


    $calendarBase64     = base64_encode(implode("\r\n",$calendarLines));
    //ensure we don't have lines longer than 70 characters for older computers:
    $calendarResult     = wordwrap($calendarBase64,68,"\n",true);

    $emailLines = array(
        "--{$boundary}",
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso - 8859 - 1\"",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable",
        "",
        "<html><body>",
        "<h1>Hello World</h1>",
        "<p>This is a calendar event test</p>",
        "</body></html>",
        "",
        "--{$boundary}",
        "Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=\"utf - 8\"; method=REQUEST",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64",
        "",
        $calendarResult,
        "",
        "--{$boundary}--"
    );
    $emailContent   = implode("\n",$emailLines);

    $headersResult      = implode("\n",$headers);
    mail($toEmail, $summary, $emailContent, $headersResult );
    echo("<pre>".htmlentities($headersResult)."\n\n".htmlentities($emailContent)."</pre>");
    echo("<br /><br />");
    echo("<pre>".base64_decode($calendarResult)."</pre>");
```